# PHP session variable within other variable

Tags: php, session

I have a page (cart page in ecommerce) with some data id like to access via PHP so I can mail it.

When I print all session variables using `print_r( $_SESSION );` I get the following code.

I want to echo the value of "**total**".

I am using `$_SESSION['cart']['total'];` but it doesn't work.

All other outputs like "currency" and "language" are displayed as they should be.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
array(22) {
  ["sessiontoken"]=>
  &string(32) "2239f469b65f039885a0c747f6595609"
  ["cart"]=>
  &object(shoppingCart)#1 (5) {
    ["contents"]=>
    array(2) {
      [216]=>
      array(1) {
        ["qty"]=>
        int(1)
      }
      [71]=>
      array(1) {
        ["qty"]=>
        int(1)
      }
    }
    ["total"]=>
    float(115.9)
    ["weight"]=>
    float(0)
    ["cartID"]=>
    &string(5) "91586"
    ["content_type"]=>
    string(8) "physical"
  }
  ["language"]=>
  &string(7) "english"
  ["languages_id"]=>
  &string(1) "1"
  ["currency"]=>
  &string(3) "USD"
  ["navigation"]=>
  &object(navigationHistory)#2 (2) {
    ["path"]=>
    array(5) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        ["page"]=>
        string(9) "index.php"
        ["mode"]=>
        string(6) "NONSSL"
        ["get"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["cPath"]=>
          string(2) "50"
        }
        ["post"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      array(4) {
        ["page"]=>
        string(7) "404.php"
        ["mode"]=>
        string(6) "NONSSL"
        ["get"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["post"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [2]=>
      array(4) {
        ["page"]=>
        string(21) "checkout_shipping.php"
        ["mode"]=>
        string(3) "SSL"
        ["get"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["post"]=>
        array(15) {
          ["formid"]=>
          string(32) "2239f469b65f039885a0c747f6595609"
          ["action"]=>
          string(7) "process"
          ["payment"]=>
          string(5) "gspay"
          ["shipping"]=>
          string(9) "flat_flat"
          ["hd_shipping"]=>
          string(5) "12.00"
          ["hd_std_shipping"]=>
          string(5) "29.00"
          ["cust_fname"]=>
          string(1) "k"
          ["cust_lname"]=>
          string(1) "k"
          ["cust_email"]=>
          string(10) "kk@kkk.xom"
          ["cust_street"]=>
          string(3) "kkk"
          ["cust_city"]=>
          string(3) "kkk"
          ["cust_state"]=>
          string(3) "kkk"
          ["cust_zip"]=>
          string(3) "222"
          ["country"]=>
          string(2) "72"
          ["btnSubmit"]=>
          string(20) "Continue to checkout"
        }
      }
      [3]=>
      array(4) {
        ["page"]=>
        string(20) "checkout_payment.php"
        ["mode"]=>
        string(3) "SSL"
        ["get"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["post"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [4]=>
      array(4) {
        ["page"]=>
        string(25) "checkout_confirmation.php"
        ["mode"]=>
        string(3) "SSL"
        ["get"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["post"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["formid"]=>
          string(32) "2239f469b65f039885a0c747f6595609"
          ["payment"]=>
          string(5) "gspay"
        }
      }
    }
    ["snapshot"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["user_type"]=>
  &string(5) "guest"
  ["sendto"]=>
  &NULL
  ["cartID"]=>
  &string(5) "91586"
  ["payment"]=>
  &string(5) "gspay"
  ["comments"]=>
  &NULL
  ["shipping"]=>
  &array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(9) "flat_flat"
    ["title"]=>
    string(53) "Global Priority Shipping (It takes 5-7 business days)"
    ["cost"]=>
    string(5) "12.00"
  }
  ["cust_fname"]=>
  &string(1) "k"
  ["cust_lname"]=>
  &string(1) "k"
  ["cust_email"]=>
  &string(10) "kk@kkk.xom"
  ["cust_street"]=>
  &string(3) "kkk"
  ["cust_city"]=>
  &string(3) "kkk"
  ["cust_state"]=>
  &string(3) "kkk"
  ["cust_zip"]=>
  &string(3) "222"
  ["cust_country"]=>
  &string(2) "72"
  ["cust_country_title"]=>
  &string(7) "Finland"
  ["billto"]=>
  &NULL
}
```

Comment: `['cart']->total`, since cart is an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cart is an object so it should be something like

```
 $_SESSION['cart']->total;
```

or if total is private or the corresponding class doesn't have a magic getter `__get()`; that could do it (or check the Class API for the public method name that returns `$this->total;`):

```
 $_SESSION['cart']->getTotal();
```

Comment: @user1721135 I believe my answer is the most generic as sometimes the variable of an object could be private and no __get() is defined in the class. If you agree please accept it as answer :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `cart` is an object.

So, you should be able to access it via:

$_SESSION['cart']->total;

Answer (score 1):

$_SESSION['cart'] is an object, then total is it's property:
$total = $_SESSION['cart']->total;

Comment: use "code block" to write code in answer. Then your answer will be highlighted. good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am a new user here (registered), I will try to keep on with rules.

Answer (score 0):

From your output,

```
["cart"]=>
  &object(shoppingCart)#1 (5) {
    ...
    }
    ["total"]=>    float(115.9)
```

The value $_SESSION['cart'] is a PHP Object. You should access the total using:

```
$_SESSION['cart']->total;
```